# How do I create an anchor tag on AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I got the URL for the logout screen but I don't know how to create an anchor tag to reference it

```
resp.getWriter().println(userService.createLogoutURL(req.getRequestURI()));
```

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altered the value of the ContentType from:

```
 resp.setContentType("text/plain");
```

to:

```
 resp.setContentType("text/html");
```

Thanks, good luck with it.